# MS Access: Hide and Unhide subform based on drop down in Main Form

Tags: forms, ms-access, combobox

Can I hide and unhide a subform based upon the output of a combobox?

Here is what I am attempting to do...

The SchedGenMain_Form (main form) has a combo box called Product_Select_Combo.  If Product_Select_Combo is populated with data, I would like the SubProduct_Form to to be visible.  If Product_Select_Combo does not have data, I would like it to be hidden.

Also, for another subform...  If Product_Select_Combo's data equals "Product 123", then I have another subform (Invoice) that I would like made visible.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Design view of your form. Click the Combobox, and go to after_update event.

In there you will be able to add the code for your form

```
Private Sub ComboBox_AfterUpdate()

    If Me.Combobox.Value = "Product 123" Then
        Forms!SubFormName.Visible = True
    Else
        Forms!SubFormName.Visible = False
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks... That was a solution for one challenge...  Ok, from a different angle...  I tried using the following on the form_Load() from the main form...  I want another subform only to appear if data is present in a combo box...                                                                                              
    If Me.Product_Select_Combo.Value Is Not Null Then
        Forms!SubProduct.Visible = True
    Else
        Forms!SubProduct.Visible = False
    End If

Comment: But I am getting the following an object required error

Comment: I am getting the same error when using the code provided:  Object Required

Comment: @CPM Try using `Forms!NameOfYourMainForm.Product_Select_Combo.Value` instead.

Comment: Do I place the code in the Subform or Main form?  any particular event?

Comment: When do you think it needs to happen? I Don't know when you want this code to function. I'm assuming you want it to be hidden when the form loads.

Comment: I want it to disappear when the main form loads, reappear on click, and disable on another click...

Comment: Not needing the conditional statement anymore

Comment: You are blowing this out of the scope of the original question. Did my answer help out your original question?

Comment: Would I place that on the on load ()?

Comment: Worked!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It's not the form but the *subform control* to hide:

```
Me!NameOfYourSubformControl.Visible = Not IsNull(Me!Product_Select_Combo.Value)
```